# angularjs loops with function or method calls

Tags: loops, angularjs, function-calls

Thanks for you help in advance.

First of all I am a beginner to angularjs as such I am running in to what I hope is a trivial challenge.
please let me know if I should change my approach.
I am running it to a problem that I need help with.
I am trying to call a function from inside a angularjs loop.

Angular set up and function to be called from inside the loop

```
function switch_img24(v){

simg = {
   //pdf icon 24 x 24
   'pdf' : 'data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAGLklEQVRIiW2UT2xc1RXGf/fPezPjscdM/EeR7aRqSgBBACmJswE2WaA2wgjVC5BYskGR2m2kSogFVYT4I1gWlSJ2sEBKlAi16iJNRauorsCJTGMrkCgQeyadxDPP43kzb96de08X8SQh6pGu7uae++n7zvcdJSIA6oMPPhBrzM8PHjr0h3K5PNFutzf6/X7TOXdbRG5rpTYFOiIiCkYFqkqpCWPMRKFQ2DU2NjbTTdP2xUuXjrfb7WsnTpxQ1lqxgBaRUKlUDh85cuTUo48+Otfr9YIx5lCe52RZRhzHhBBI0xSAcrmMMYY8zzHGUCqVCCGEUqmkq9Xqub+dP7/ovf/aWqstoJ1zYWpq6ukDBw7Mffrpp25packUCoUwOzsre/bsYWVlhRCCeuKJJ8id49uVFYwxcuDAAfI8Z21tjTRN1fz8vHvttdd+trq2Nu+c+7pQKGgNiNaaTqfTyPOcVqtlarWa/vHHH/W+ffvM1taWOXjwoBkZGdGlUknn/b6en5/XzjkzPT1tLl68aBqNhqnVarrVamnnHJ1O579aawA0gFKKfr+/5b0nSRLq9Tr1ep3t7W2q1SrfffcdzWaT5eVl3n777btyFYtFSqUS6+vr1Ot1kiRR3nuyLEuUUgByl0G/399yzpEkia7X69RqNZxznDt3jvfee480TamMVXjhhQWazSYbGxtc/vZbzp46xe1Gg1qtRpIkeuAcWZYlQwZ2yCDP87Zzrl+r1Qrr6+sCqD998gmrq6u0t7b48ssvWVhYoNVq8fHHf2R0fJybacqV9Q2ikRIuSaRWr6vcuTzP860hAwsIgPd+u9VqdY8fP144duwYxWLxrgxDx6RpCiK8sLCA5Dny1luM7KoSxsfpnjzJ3sceo9Vspt777fsBAAghdNvtdufZZ5+tHj16VADF/yvvwRh45x24fh0efxxOn4b9+6WfZeo/ly93vPfpDgD2Xp/vZVm23e316Ha7DB/8pJxDJiexZ89SPHECmZ6me+oUsn8/JknIQ6CfZdve+979AAKoEIL0er271B4EUN4jlQrm++8Zef11NNB99130I49gkhbX63WRIDjntkMIQwVED/sBBs71CAF58AwGhChCul2Kr76KqtUYHDlCePll+o0Ga1ev8cP1H3ZIunS4fu6XSHZuHUJARO5J5D3EMWIMo79exCwtoQC3uMjNToeNlRUcEEURiHBnVd2ruwBKKWwUlX0Id5wrAoMBUi4DUHnpJeJ//gPKZTbTlKu7d9NeW0WLYK3FOUcQwVhbHsoMd5KsALTWNo7jMe8ckueEEAiTk9hbt5h45hnMlSvcfOUVltOUbyoV2pUKNgjKmCFjFUIgjuMxfSdlAqjhDDDGlGJrK1IqwdSUEmMwH32EPPkk11st/v3hh6xcuMAmYMtl7GgZ7pMzSEBrTRxFY8aY4s4csMNpW61HC5VK+fbnn7N95gz64kVcvU7/xRfxb7yBWVoiWl1FAQHwQcB7Ymvp5zmTE5NqV7VKvd8ftdaWRaT7kxxYaytRuTzSWfoXyd/PE/3yV7C4iH74YSIgfPUVg53PdZZRMpqJuTm2mk1KIyVmZ2bI+n0ia0estWMicgtQdicDxIXCuM5zM3PokMS/+a3KyiP4ZgvZ7sBomcLaGiNABUW10yE8VGV9x8YzM3sZeK+C91hr4yiKKvdLhIhQsPYhGR+n+ue/yO5Tp9XNL74AaxEboXs9djcaRIBYg3KOq998Q3L4ML+YmSF4j4jgQwjaGB3H8fgwCxpQIkJcLFb1dofGm29KtLxM5f33YWISHUXYzU2iW7cQEAXSBjYuXGDv3r13BhwCSikkBFFK8SAAIkKpXJ4uIWR79vjayZO++NlnfrC+HjIR8UmCn5jAz82pMDurrlarzDYa6G43dLMs5Hnue72eH3jvi4UCxWJx6n6JfBRF3Lhx47QfDF56+qmnjnaff16y555TgxAYJAnZ7AzNM2d8CMEJoIyJnVK6v7WljbXoO1aVQhybS5cunavX63+Noggg3F12g8HgxrVr1xbSNP1dZO1Yz7mNQZ43EWlqY1ramC0R6aEUWqnyIIRxcW6XUmoyiuOJUqk0l/V6t29vbv5+MBhkO+YM/wPiLY53hbn7BgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==',

   //document icon 24 x 24
   'doc' : 'data:;base64,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',
   'docx': 'data:;base64,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',

   //folder open icon 24 x 24
   'fop' : 'data:;base64,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',

   //folder closed icon 24 x 24
   'fcl' : 'data:;base64,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',

   //folder zipped icon 24 x 24
   'zip' : 'data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAADz0lEQVR42qWVf2wTZRjHv++16/WuXX+wX3Qlw4nBIZo5a2ZYMiMmGBVJtgUWom6Ki6IYgzEoCWGZIJqwCEYxoImZhCWK/iEi/sGPvxZMjDDpCvth4oAF0hIQWHstvbbX3uu91/W6xW7Z6pNc7v35fJ7nfe++D6GUghkhBLn2tRs3s41ZLJFKYWh0DO3PPUNYP3TrH5AC6zyVFSA5p/2ftqNj2484+e2mgs4zlEMgvBxsknIWWEU77qt9AOvXrCZn/Rd9LEBmJo5DqSBEHDZhvKbakwecP/Y2qhq3Uzp+AK0TT+J7X8UMAH/3F3w36NDbFl6Eu9KL5sbGghl+3XcY+3Z1k9HLVwUDsKGlCd1d9WFFUZyznY+qrb0zKSOdUSFVd6JuWY0xd0/O4I4UhRSXMXD6JOof82kBPO4yAInbJ46UmJWOuc5eVSkUJZ09MlVF/wBfcN3lsRFs3eg5JJU8/Y4BCP/9JbW75rzb/1gylca165M4fMZqjHU9mwTHEZSYuAgqXs9nEP2rl/Iuy4IAzGLxJGLCqxgMBOAfuoSXnpqE2WyCU7RI6fI3nAYgNvoJNTv4BQMy2n3sPqIY/c7VUdhtPBYvskv80m3TAMMfU2I3LxjA9t+1bjIyaF91EzbRAk9ZqSTcv306YA+lPFkwgNmeo/l9L666rWfAAOLyHTMBaZNaFEBybTYyaG24DqddB9wT63ba85d88SOaglIUoPd4/iva0BCCwyGguswB+8puYgCkwG6azCSKAsierUYG61aMw1UqwFvphO3hnjwgMrSLyql4UYDPTjmNdsvKCZQ5RVSVuxBbvCUPCPs/pHE5WhQgXfuBkcHzy0bhdogoczshed6cDuhJynJs3n9a1PvurHNM7DY3h5GoeUs0AJMXen41Ebp2Ps5/GLRBXORF3YpHdZHL2Zxid/zQywi622g6clXT8OwmojJhy+kTe09975wJosuLBGwFA2Bix+R67MpEvh7k7ODRn2gqdmsKoGgu1axzOgXQCgsxW2ESK7BlY5tO3Ll3v+4kFAqi7/N9+tjI+BWUiuJMwA2t9IVCIcQTCa0sKrBYeE24zDBpj9Vq1VSSy4I1FylNtn0PPaj3WYn97fc/EBgZxt7uHYT5YTajZM7X6p9owomfj+mbajxVerTnLwzRiHb2wUgMr6xdQ3JQPZhiAG2tLVSSk1jqrdbHWta9gN4vDsDX1IzhwXPGWofAFwf45quD9Kz/Erxerz5WW+5OD2j/gJ7VkiW6JAeDQTQ3PPL/AO+91qEfx7k//UoO8H5XZwl77+/rpwzwLyCH1tgcRQHiAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC',

   //excel icon 24 x 24
   'xlsx': 'data:;base64,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',
   'xls' : 'data:;base64,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',

   //database icon 24 x 24
   'db'  : 'data:;base64,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',
}

return simg[v]

}

function allDocCtrl($scope){
    //this will eventually be an ajax call but for now I have it as a hidden field 
$scope.docsJson = $.parseJSON($("#doc_json").val());

//['file_name','regular_url','file_list','dir_name','dir_list']
rtn_html = ''

$scope.getExt = function(str){
    var pattern = /\.[0-9a-z]+$/i;
    var ext = (str).match(pattern);
    var img = switch_img24(ext)
    return img
}
}
```

HTML

```
<input type='hidden' id='doc_json' value='{'file_list':[  
    {
"file_name":"file.doc",
"url":"api/path..."
},  
{
"file_name":"file.pdf",
"url":"api/path..."
},  
{
"file_name":"file.txt",
"url":"api/path..."
},  
]}'/>  

<div id='due-diligence' ng-controller='allDocCtrl'>

 <li ng-repeat="doc in docsJson.file_list">
    {[{doc.file_name}]} who is {[{doc.url}]} years old.
    <img src=getExt( doc.file_name )   width='15' height='15' />
 </li>

</div>
```

So the challenge I have is to call the getExt( doc.file_name ) from within the loop
any and all help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [`ng-src`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc)

```
<img ng-src="{{getExt( doc.file_name )}}"/>
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/TkAgQ/).

Other notes:

1. You are missing some `;` inside of your `scope.getExt()` function.
2. `rtn_html = ''` is missing a `;` and appears to be global, missing `var`?
3. `getExt` and `switch_img24()` might be better accomplished with a filter.  So you could do:

`<img ng-src="{{doc.file_name | getExtImage}}"/>`

Comment: I just discovered that but it is still not working?          <img ng-src="{[{ getExt(doc.file_name) }]}"    width='15' height='15' />

Comment: It is working my regx is messed up causing the whole thing to break